# Built-In arguments separator

Tags: powerbi

i have this problem with my PowerBi Desktop installation: when i try to use some built In functions, the PowerBi intellisense doesn't show me any arguments separator in the arguments list. For ex, if try to use GENERATESERIES, after typing the first bracket powerbi show me this:

GENERATESERIES(**StartValue**StopValue[IncrementValue])

With the DATE function the behaviour is the same:

DATE(**Year**MonthDay)

As a result i'm not able to write something like GENERATESERIES(1,52,1) because it told me that the statement is not valid.

I have win10 (1903) English and PowerBi Version: 2.71.5523.941 64-bit (luglio 2019) with English language and Italian Regional Setting

Comment: Obviously, good morning all (sorry)

Comment: I dont know why but after changed the decimal separator to "." (instead of ",") and restored the default values ( "," as decimal separator), it runs correctly showing me the ";" as arguments separator! Really funny!!! it looks like ghost hunting!